# URL Rewrite is not working properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my URL rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^cars/$ cars.php    
RewriteRule ^cars/([a-z-]+)/$ /cars.php?model=$1
```

This works, so my URL is like this:

> example.com/cars/porche/

refers to

> cars.php?model=porche

Now Im making more search criterias, so I want to be able to add for example model year, car manufactor, etc. like this:

> example.com/cars/porche/?model_year=xxx&car_manufactor=xxx

Right now this does not work with the current rewrite, but  I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just add `QSA`:

```
RewriteRule ^cars/([a-z-]+)/$ /cars.php?model=$1 [QSA]
```

That tells the rewrite engine to append any other query parameters to the rewritten URL as well.